Correct way to update a table in a different database in a DBT pipeline
I have a data pipeline implemented in DBT with Snowflake.
All of my existing models are defined as simple SQL select statements, as is typical.
At the end of the pipeline, I want to insert one row into a external table called METRICS which is in a different database in the same Snowflake account.
To more explicitly define the structure of my data. The pipeline database will look like this:
MY_DATABASE
    PUBLIC
        MODEL_1
        MODEL_2
        MODEL_3
OTHER_DATABASE
    PUBLIC
        METRICS

I want my query to be a select that uses data from MODEL_1, MODEL_2, and MODEL_3 to produce some metrics in a single row of data and insert this row into OTHER_DATABASE.PUBLIC.METRICS.
I looked into the concept of "incremental models" but this doesn't seem to quite match what I'm trying to do.
One other idea I had was to

a)write a model in the existing pipeline that collects the metrics (which will be a single row)
b) use a post hook to copy the resulting row into the external table.

This is what I will probably do if I can't think of something better.
Is there a better or more idiomatic way to do this?

If I understand correctly, you would like to build a model based on MODEL_1, MODEL_2, MODEL_3 and that model should write to OTHER_DATABASE.PUBLIC.METRICS.
To achieve that you can override generate_schema_name macro and create a new macro.sql(name of the macro does not matter) under macros folder.You can further read in the DBT Documentation
You can create
{% macro generate_schema_name(custom_schema_name, node) -%}

    {%- set default_schema = target.schema -%}
    {%- if custom_schema_name is none -%}

        {{ default_schema }}

    {%- else -%}

        {{ default_schema }}_{{ custom_schema_name | trim }}

    {%- endif -%}

{%- endmacro %}

As you can see custom_schema_name is passed onto this macro, so in the dbt_project.yml  you can define the custom_schema_name and database like so
models:
  your_project:
    project_name: #  Grouping or folder for set of models
      +database: OTHER_DATABASE
      +schema: PUBLIC

